# Two columns on x-axis and different grids in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggraph

I need some help with a graph in R.

This is how my dataframe looks like

| Footprint | Local Number | Remote Number | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.4 | 45 | 4 | L1 |
| 12.5 | 452 | 78 | L9 |
| 15.6 | 86 | 52 | L5 |
| 85.3 | 12 | 12 | L4 |
| 12.5 | 35 | 36 | L2 |
| 85.9 | 78 | 78 | L3 |
| 78.5 | 44 | 44 | L6 |
| 4.6 | 10 | 11 | L7 |
| 13.9 | 157 | 2 | L8 |

What I want to achieve is a graph with the 'Footprint' column in the y-axis, the 'Local Number' column(in the x-axis) in the positive grid of the graph and the 'Remote Number' column(in the x-axis) in the negative grid of the graph. The data should be presented in dots and the lab name should be the label. So basically, I want to show for each location the remote and local number of employees.
I am struggling on presenting the two columns in the x-axis. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried?

Comment: Your `Remote Number` column just consists of the word `row` - is that a mistake? should these actually be numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you want something like where you could use `geom_point` for both columns with one negative and positive and add labels using `geom_text` like this:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'Footprint  Local_Number    Remote_Number   Location
10.4    45  4   L1
12.5    452 78  L9
15.6    86  52  L5
85.3    12  12  L4
12.5    35  36  L2
85.9    78  78  L3
78.5    44  44  L6
4.6 10  11  L7
13.9    157 2   L8
', header = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = Footprint, y = Local_Number, color = '1')) +
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = -Remote_Number, y = Local_Number, color = '2')) +
  geom_text(df, mapping = aes(x = Footprint, y = Local_Number, label = Location), hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  geom_text(df, mapping = aes(x = -Remote_Number, y = Local_Number, label = Location), hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend', labels = c('Footprint', 'Remote number'), values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  labs(y = 'Local Number')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

If you want to show it on only a positive axis you could the negative sign like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = Footprint, y = Local_Number, color = '1')) +
  geom_point(df, mapping = aes(x = Remote_Number, y = Local_Number, color = '2')) +
  geom_text(df, mapping = aes(x = Footprint, y = Local_Number, label = Location), hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  geom_text(df, mapping = aes(x = Remote_Number, y = Local_Number, label = Location), hjust = 0, vjust = 0) +
  scale_color_manual('Legend', labels = c('Footprint', 'Remote number'), values = c('blue', 'red')) +
  labs(y = 'Local Number')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here two more suggestions for visualisation. This seems to be paired data - remote vs local number. That can be either represented as a scatter plot or as change.

Footprint can then be encoded as color. Thanks +1 to Quieten for the data.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = 'Footprint  Local_Number    Remote_Number   Location
10.4    45  4   L1
12.5    452 78  L9
15.6    86  52  L5
85.3    12  12  L4
12.5    35  36  L2
85.9    78  78  L3
78.5    44  44  L6
4.6 10  11  L7
13.9    157 2   L8
', header = TRUE)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Local_Number, Remote_Number)) +
  ## use Number as x and y and color code by footprint value
  geom_point(aes(color = Footprint), size = 3) +
  ## label the points, best with repel
  ggrepel::geom_text_repel(aes(label = Location)) +
  ## optional add a line of equality to help intuitive recognition of change
  ## + keeping same limits helps intuitive comparison
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1, lty = 2, size = .3) +
  coord_equal(xlim = range(c(df$Local_Number, df$Remote_Number)), ylim = range(c(df$Local_Number, df$Remote_Number))) +
  ## optional change color scale
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "magma")
```

[image]

```r
  
## or, not to waste half of your graph (there is no positive value)
## you can show the difference instead
df %>%
  mutate(change = Local_Number-Remote_Number) %>%
  ggplot() +
  ## now use Location as x variable, therefore no labels needed any more
  geom_point(aes(Location, change, color = Footprint), size = 3) +
 ## optional change color scale
  scale_color_viridis_c(option = "magma")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>